# Custom chart based on Q3DScatter with QCustom3DItem going slow

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl, 3d

I want to make a 3D chart with bars, the bar color depends on its size. Both [Qt bar and scatter graph types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-overview.html) are close to what I'm looking for. I ended up creating a chart based on `Q3DScatter` and adding `QCustom3DItem`  to draw the bars, so I can set a mesh item and color to each item. I have one item in each position of the chart. Let's say it's a 100x100 chart, meaning there are 10 000 bars (custom items).

I want to redraw the entire chart multiple times per second. By redraw I mean every item will change its size and color. To set item size I call [setScalling()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcustom3ditem.html#scaling-prop). Because scalling works by keeping the item center position (and I want to keep the bar base position) then I have to call [setPosition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcustom3ditem.html#position-prop) just after scalling. And to set color I call [setTextureImage()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcustom3ditem.html#setTextureImage). So, multiple times per second, code like the following get's called:

```
for (int col = 0; col < 100; col++)
  for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
    items[row*COLS+col]->setScalling(scale);
    items[row*COLS+col]->setPosition(position);
    items[row*COLS+col]->setTextureImage(image);
  }
```

This works almost as expected. Problem is not fast enough. Any hints on how to make it faster?

I tried to move custom items to another thread.

In order to move processsing (i.e. scalling) of `QCustom3DItem` out of main (gui) thread I do:

project.pro

```
QT += core gui widgets datavisualization
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp graphdata.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h graphdata.h

RESOURCES += mesh.qrc

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = debug
} else {
    DESTDIR = release
}
OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR/
MOC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/
RCC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/
UI_DIR = $$DESTDIR/
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "graphdata.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread thread;
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:
    void start();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    resize(400,300);

    auto graph = new Q3DScatter;
    auto container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);
    setCentralWidget(container);

    auto data = new GraphData(graph);
    data->moveToThread(&thread);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::start, data, &GraphData::start);
    thread.start();
    emit start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    thread.quit();
    thread.wait();
}
```

graphdata.h

```
class GraphData : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q3DScatter* m_graph;
    QCustom3DItem* item;
public:
    explicit GraphData(Q3DScatter* m_graph);

public slots:
    void start();
    void setData(int scale);
};

#endif // GRAPHDATA_H
```

graphdata.cpp

```
#include "graphdata.h"

GraphData::GraphData(Q3DScatter* graph) : m_graph(graph){}

void GraphData::start() {
    item = new QCustom3DItem;
    item->setMeshFile(QStringLiteral(":mesh.obj"));
    m_graph->addCustomItem(item);
}

void GraphData::setData(int scale) {
//    item->setScaling();
}
```

mesh.qrc

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource>
        <file>mesh.obj</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

mesh.obj

```
# Blender v2.80 (sub 75) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
o Cube
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.625000 0.000000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.000000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.375000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.125000 0.750000
vt 0.125000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.875000 0.750000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
s off
f 5/1/1 3/2/1 1/3/1
f 3/4/2 8/5/2 4/6/2
f 7/7/3 6/8/3 8/5/3
f 2/9/4 8/10/4 6/8/4
f 1/11/5 4/12/5 2/13/5
f 5/14/6 2/9/6 6/15/6
f 5/1/1 7/16/1 3/2/1
f 3/4/2 7/7/2 8/5/2
f 7/7/3 5/17/3 6/8/3
f 2/9/4 4/18/4 8/10/4
f 1/11/5 3/19/5 4/12/5
f 5/14/6 1/20/6 2/9/6
```

This looks like to be working, the `QCustom3DItem` is on another thread, though there is the warning:

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

My understanding is that `m_graph->addCustomItem(item)` is trying to change `item` parent and is failing. How should I deal with this?

Should I expect better performance by processing custom items on another thread?

Comment: protip: if you change your cube mesh so the origin (0,0,0) is in the middle of its bottom face, then you won't need to call `setPosition`.

Answer (score 3):

Qt is good for prototyping or non performance critical code. However, its object oriented approach is in odds with how the hardware works, making it hard to impossible to write performant code.

Your best bet is to override the drawing code to render all the bars in one call. If supporting old hardware is a requirement, go with generating a VBO with all the vertices and send that in one `glDrawArrays` call. If recent hardware is okay then you can generate all the mesh on the GPU through instancing, and fetching bar heights from a texture. In the later case you will need to only send 10,000 floats per frame, which is nothing in terms of bandwidth.

Bottom line: Rendering 10,000 cubes in real-time is a piece of cake for modern GPUs. Qt is your bottleneck.