# QCustom3DItem on another thread leads to QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl, qobject

In order to move scalling of `QCustom3DItem` out of main (gui) thread I do:

project.pro

```
QT += core gui widgets datavisualization
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp graphdata.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h graphdata.h

RESOURCES += mesh.qrc

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    DESTDIR = debug
} else {
    DESTDIR = release
}
OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR/
MOC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/
RCC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/
UI_DIR = $$DESTDIR/
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "graphdata.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread thread;
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
signals:
    void start();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    resize(400,300);

    auto graph = new Q3DScatter;
    auto container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);
    setCentralWidget(container);

    auto data = new GraphData(graph);
    data->moveToThread(&thread);
    connect(this, &MainWindow::start, data, &GraphData::start);
    thread.start();
    emit start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    thread.quit();
    thread.wait();
}
```

graphdata.h

```
class GraphData : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q3DScatter* m_graph;
    QCustom3DItem* item;
public:
    explicit GraphData(Q3DScatter* m_graph);

public slots:
    void start();
    void setData(int scale);
};

#endif // GRAPHDATA_H
```

graphdata.cpp

```
#include "graphdata.h"

GraphData::GraphData(Q3DScatter* graph) : m_graph(graph){}

void GraphData::start() {
    item = new QCustom3DItem;
    item->setMeshFile(QStringLiteral(":mesh.obj"));
    m_graph->addCustomItem(item);
}

void GraphData::setData(int scale) {
//    item->setScaling();
}
```

mesh.qrc

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource>
        <file>mesh.obj</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

mesh.obj

```
# Blender v2.80 (sub 75) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
o Cube
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.625000 0.000000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.000000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.375000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.125000 0.750000
vt 0.125000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.875000 0.750000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
s off
f 5/1/1 3/2/1 1/3/1
f 3/4/2 8/5/2 4/6/2
f 7/7/3 6/8/3 8/5/3
f 2/9/4 8/10/4 6/8/4
f 1/11/5 4/12/5 2/13/5
f 5/14/6 2/9/6 6/15/6
f 5/1/1 7/16/1 3/2/1
f 3/4/2 7/7/2 8/5/2
f 7/7/3 5/17/3 6/8/3
f 2/9/4 4/18/4 8/10/4
f 1/11/5 3/19/5 4/12/5
f 5/14/6 1/20/6 2/9/6
```

This looks like to be working, the `QCustom3DItem` is on another thread, though there is the warning:

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

My understanding is that `m_graph->addCustomItem(item)` is trying to change `item` parent and is failing. How should I deal with this?

Should I expect better performance by processing custom items on another thread?

Comment: You should not modify the GUI from another thread, in your case Q3DScatter is part of the thread and the start method is executed in another thread, the message states that, in addition QCustom3DItem is also part of the GUI so you should not create it in another thread. Why the need for thread? The scaling and other modifications of the GUI are optimized to run in the main thread so I don't see the need for additional threads to do that task

Comment: The need for thread is mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597182/custom-chart-based-on-q3dscatter-with-qcustom3ditem-going-slow

Comment: As you suspect you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377), that is to say you are asked about a possible solution that nobody guarantees that it works (as you observe it yourself) instead of the real problem.

Comment: I recommend you to rewrite your previous question stating: "I want to get X but when executing it in the main thread it is very slow, so I try to solve it by moving tasks such as scaling in another thread but it is failing since it indicates this warning, what is it? the proper way to solve this problem? " and delete your current question. So you give the community the problem completely and not in pieces like now where to understand your question we need to read 2 post.

Comment: So, in which thread the item actually is? My understanding it is on another thread, which is what I was expecting.

Comment: In your case you are creating it in another thread, but this item has other internal elements that can only and should live in the main thread, for example, where was the painting done? according to your logic in the secondary thread but Qt only does the painting in the main thread since for example the QPainter is not thread-safe. I recommend you read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

Comment: Updated the first question, sorry for the mistaken approach to break the problem into smaller pieces. Also checked the link though I don't see what else can I move to a worker thread, looks like the expensive part is to play with the custom items and if I can't move that to another thread then what can be done?